# HTML Grid Tables with Pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

I want to convert a markdown that includes a table to HTML. The table should have a grid.

Markdown:

```
| Column A | Column B |
|:--------:|:--------:|
|    1     |    2     |
|    3     |    4     |
```

pandoc command that I tried:  `pandoc -t html5 -f gfm -o output.html tmp_markdown.md`

This results in an HTML table without a grid:

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th style="text-align: center;">Column A</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">Column B</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Can I adjust the style of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option in Markdown, but you could try to add a CSS snippet in your Markdown file:

```
<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { border: solid black 1px; padding: 0 1ex; }
</style>
```

This will add solid black borders around all table cells, creating a grid.